# Test automation tools for desktop application

Tags: qt, testing

Is there any GUI / functionality test automation tools for testing QT3 based GUI applications? I went through [LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/), [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/), [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/), and [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) but all dependent on specific QT versions.

Also, Sikuli is not reliable.

Any others?

Comment: From our point of view, this is a rather specialized requirement. If you don't get an answer after a couple of days, consider having your question migrated to [sqa.se]. Don't repost, flag your question and ask a moderator to do the migration.

Comment: Are you tied down to Qt3 as a requirement? It is horrendously out of date now that Qt 5.1 is released.  It would be worth the time to at least bring it up to 4.x

Comment: I solved it by using squish.
I cannot change the qt version.